# Change the language of OSM maps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, maps, internationalization

I would like to create small walking paper maps of Chinese cities parts and thought to use QGIS(print pdf + via plotting). With QuickMapServices plugin I added the map and of course the street names are in Chinese. Using the info OSM plugin I've seen that the data are partially available in English. [image]
I therefore ask whether it is possible to display street names in English or other Western characters.

Answer (score 4):

You can not change the content of pre-renderd tiles. Since there seems to be no tile server with english labelling worldwide, you have to do it on your own:

- Render the tiles using the Mapnik toolchain or Maperitive using the `name:en` field instead of the `name` field for labelling. Add them with the TileLayer plugin to your project.
- Using the QuickOSM plugin, download elements that have a `name:en` tag, set the rendering to transparent, and label inside QGIS with the `name_en` field.

[image]

This will leave many elements unnamed though.